# Add item to array in the same dimention

Tags: php, arrays

how can add item to array? i tried this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($results); $i++) 
{ 
    $results[$i][] = array('test' => 'sdsa');
}

print_r($results);
```

but the result is this for each element ->

```
Array( 
     [0] => Array( 
         [playerid] => 0 
         [nickname] => Jeffrey_Westh 
         [score] => 2 
         [ping] => 123 
         [0] => Array ( 
                   [test] => sdsa  
         ) 
     )
```

i and need make this:

```
 Array( 
         [0] => Array( 
             [playerid] => 0 
             [nickname] => Jeffrey_Westh 
             [score] => 2 
             [ping] => 123 
             [test] => sdsa  

         )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `[]` would always add a new element into the array. In your case a new unindexed key is created and given the value of `array('test' => 'sdsa')`. Then the `0` index is given to the element.

You actually need to use `test` key. And please move `sizeof` out of `for` loop, this gives performance issues.

```
$size = sizeof($results);

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) 
{ 
    $results[$i]['test'] = 'sdsa';
}

print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($results); $i++) 
{ 
    $results[$i]["test"] = "sdsa";
}

print_r($results);
```